# Get contacts where contact has messages from firebase using firebase ui

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I'm using Firebase-UI to show a list of contacts. It works similarly to whatsapp in that if the contacts email address is in your phone and they use my app they are added to your profile in the database. I now want to only show contacts if they have messages between them. currently I give my firebase adapter this query and it retrieves all contacts

```
databaseReference.child("users")
.child(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser())
.getUid()).child("contacts")
```

what I want now is to essentially loop through them and check if they have messages (which I'm not sure how to do from the firebase adapter option builder) any help?

**FIREBASE ADAPTER**

```
    public class FirebaseContactsAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contact, ContactViewHolder> {

      private Context context;
      private final ItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener;
      private final String TAG = "FbCntctAdptr";

      public FirebaseContactsAdapter(
          @NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contact> options, Context context, ItemTouchListener onItemTouchListener) {
        super(options);
        this.context = context;
        this.onItemTouchListener = onItemTouchListener;
      }

      @NonNull
      @Override
      public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.contact_holder, parent, false);
        return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
      }


      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ContactViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contact contact) {

        onBind(holder, position, contact);

      }

      private void onBind(ViewHolder holder, int position, Contact contact){
        ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder = (ContactViewHolder) holder;

        contactViewHolder.contactNameTextView.setText(contact.getUserName());
        if (contact.getLastMessage() != null && !contact.getLastMessage().isEmpty()){
          contactViewHolder.lastMessage.setText(contact.getLastMessage());
        }
        if (contact.getLastMessageDate() != null && !contact.getLastMessageDate().isEmpty()){
          contactViewHolder.lastMessageDate.setText(getTimeText(contact.getLastMessageDate()));
        }
        if (contact.getUnreadMessageCount() > 0){
          contactViewHolder.unreadCountHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          contactViewHolder.unreadCount.setText(contact.getUnreadMessageCount());
        } else {
          contactViewHolder.unreadCountHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(contact.getUserImage())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image_placeholder)
            .into(contactViewHolder.contactImageView);

    //    GlideApp.with(context).load(contact.getUserImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_image_placeholder).into(contactViewHolder.contactImageView);


      }

      @Override
      public void onDataChanged() {
        super.onDataChanged();
        Log.d(TAG,"item count " + getItemCount());
      }

      @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount();
      }

      @NonNull
      @Override
      public Contact getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
      }

      private String getTimeText(String dateText){

        if (DateUtils.isToday(DateStringConverter.getDateFromString(dateText).getTime())){
          SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
          return simpleDateFormat.format(DateStringConverter.getDateFromString(dateText));
        } else if (DateUtils.isToday(DateStringConverter.getDateFromString(dateText).getTime() - 604800000)){
          SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
          return simpleDateFormat.format(DateStringConverter.getDateFromString(dateText));
        } else {
          SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
          return simpleDateFormat.format(DateStringConverter.getDateFromString(dateText));
        }

      }


      public class ContactViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        private ImageView contactImageView;
        private TextView contactNameTextView;
        private TextView unreadCount;
        private ConstraintLayout unreadCountHolder;
        private ConstraintLayout holder;
        private TextView lastMessage;
        private TextView lastMessageDate;

        public ContactViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          contactImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image);
          contactNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
          unreadCountHolder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unread_holder);
          unreadCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unread_count_text);
          lastMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_status);
          lastMessageDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
          holder = itemView.findViewById(R.id.holder);
          holder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              onItemTouchListener.onCardClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
            }
          });
        }
      }

    }
```

**CALLING THE ADAPTER**

```
setUpFirebaseContactAdapter(databaseReference.child("users").child(Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).getUid()).child("contacts"));

  private void setUpFirebaseContactAdapter(Query query){
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions options = buildFirebaseRecyclerOptions(query);
    firebaseAdapter = new FirebaseContactsAdapter(options, getActivity(), this  );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
  }
```

**BUILD OPTIONS**

```
private FirebaseRecyclerOptions buildFirebaseRecyclerOptions(Query query){
      return new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contact>()
              .setQuery(query, Contact.class)
              .setLifecycleOwner(this)
              .build();
    }
```

FYI if your suggestion is for me to structure my data differently could you add a small picture of how it could be done currently I have it like this [image: data structure] and that sentences node is nothing to do with messages or contacts (education app)

Comment: sir for messages and the problem i understand from your question this link will help you for chat purpose very easily. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-TiA3SFVAQ&list=PLGCjwl1RrtcQ3o2jmZtwu2wXEA4OIIq53&index=28

Comment: @HasnainSabir Thank you but I'm not having trouble with chat messages, please read the question before replying, my issue is showing a data set from firebase where a child exists